# Elementary Set Theory - Countable Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I have to show that the following set is countable: the set of all integers divisible by 8.

Let's say that A is the set of all integers divisible by 8. For a set to be countable, it has to be an function $f: A \to \mathbb N$ which is injective, and $\mathbb N \to  A$ to be bijective.

A surely can't be a countable set if it isn't injective of the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N$, as $A$ can include negative numbers?

Help appreciated!

Comment: The function sending $8k$ to itself if $k\ge0$ and $8k$ to $|8k|+1$ if $k<0$ is an injection from your set to $\mathbb{N}$. What about the other direction?

Comment: @Alessandro Sorry can you elaborate what you mean in a clearer sense?

Comment: @Alessandro I understand what you mean now. Why do you need |8k|+1 when k<0 when that isn't an integer divisible by 8?

Comment: we want to write an injective function $A\to\mathbb{N}$ so we can use any number in the second set. I'm using $|8k|+1$ just to be sure it's positive and it's not already used in the $k>0$ case (otherwise it wouldn't be injective)

Comment: Another possibility would be to send $8k$ in $2k$ when $k\ge0$ and $8k$ in $2|k|-1$ when $k<0$, actually do you notice anything about this function?

Comment: @Alessandro Okay I understand the use of |8k|+1 when k < 0. However, that will give an answer which isn't divisible by 8. So how can it work?

Comment: you're mapping from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$, for every number in $A$ you need to choose a number in $\mathbb{N}$, it doesn't need to be divisible by $8$, that's a restriction on the elements of $A$

Comment: @Alessandro Ahhhhh great! Thank-you friend I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a set defined as $A=\{i\in\mathbb{Z}:i=8k\text{ for some integer }k\}$.

Notice that the set $A$ is a subset of the set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$.i.e., $A\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$. The set $\mathbb{Z}$ is a countable set. Since every subset of a countable set is either finite or countable, the set $A$ is either finite or countable. Thus to show that $A$ is countable, it suffices to show that $A$ is not finite. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the set $A$ is finite. Since $A$ is finite, there exists a bijection $f:A\to\{j\in\mathbb{N}:1\le j\le n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Note that $8k\in A$ for all $1\le k\le n$. Thus for each $1\le k\le n$, $f(8k)=l$ for some $1\le l\le n$. Now $8(n+1)\in A$. Since $f$ is a bijection, $f(8(n+1))=m$ for some $1\le m\le n$. But this contradicts the fact that $f$ is one-one. Therefore $A$ cannot be finite and is hence countable.